# Что такое (float*)?

Tags: c, float

Программировал на Си, обучаясь по книге и увидел `(float*)`.

код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,num;
    float *data;

    printf("Введите кол-во элементов: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    data = (float*) calloc(num, sizeof(float));
    
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0;i < num;++i)
    {
        printf("Введите элемент %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%f",data+i);
    }

    for (i = 1;i < num;++i)
    {
        if (*data < *(data + i))
        {
            *data = *(data + i);
        }
    }

    printf("Максимум = %.2f\n",*data);

    return 0;
}
```

Код работает, но когда присваивается переменная data, то там находится некий `(float*)`.

Comment: Это каст (преобразование) в тип `float *`. Здесь в С он бесполезен, тут он нужен только если компилировать это как С++.

Answer (score 1):

Запись `( тип ) объект` означает создание объекта типа `тип` с инициализатором `объект`.

**6.5.4** **Cast operators**

Preceding an expression by a parenthesized type name converts the value of the expression to the unqualified version of the named type. This construction is called a cast. *A cast does not yield an lvalue.* A cast that specifies no conversion has no effect on the type or value of an expression.

If the value of the expression is represented with greater range or precision than required by the type named by the cast (6.3.1.8), then the cast specifies a conversion even if the type of the expression is the same as the named type and removes any extra range and precision.

**6.5.4** **Операторы приведения**

Предшествующее выражению имя типа, заключенное в круглые скобки, преобразует значение выражения в неполную версию указанного типа. Эта конструкция называется приведением. *Приведение не приводит к lvalue.* Приведение, в котором не установлено преобразование, не влияет на тип или значение выражения.

Если значение выражения представлено с б'ольшим диапазоном или точностью, чем требуется для типа, указанного приведением (6.3.1.8), то приведение определяет преобразование, даже если тип выражения совпадает с именованным типом, и удаляет любой дополнительный диапазон и точность.

Функция `calloc` возвращает указатель типа `void *` и этот указатель будет основой создания нового объекта типа `float *`. То-есть на самом деле то-же самый указатель, но на другой тип.

*Язык Си автоматически выполняет приведения типа `void *` к другому типу указателя. И это приведение можно опускать.*

```c
data = calloc(num, sizeof(float)); // ok
```

Comment: Ничего он не выполняет, просто потому что тип `void *`, является указателем на объект. Любой объект.

Answer (score 0):

(float*) - Это явное приведение типов void* к float* . Приведение типов - это превращение информации из одного типа в другой. Например:

```
char a = 'm'; int b = a; printf("%d", b);
```

Этот код выведет число 109, потому что 109 - это буква m в виде int. Это приведение называется неявным, потому что мы не указываем, в какой тип мы превращаем. А этот код будет с явным приведением:

```
int c = 33; char d = (char) c; printf("%c", d);
```

Этот код приводит число 33 к символьной форме. Обратите внимание, что (char) - это специальная конструкция для явного приведения типов. Мы явно указываем, что  мы приводим типы не случайно, чтобы компилятор не ругался. В вашем случае:

```
data = (float*) calloc(num, sizeof(float));
```

Здесь приводится результат функции calloc в виде void* к float* при помощи (float*) . На самом деле, он необязателен, и поставлен на всякий случай, ведь компилятор поймёт, что будет вполне нормально привести эти типы без потери информации. По этому вы можете написать код и без него:

```
data = calloc(num, sizeof(float));
```